# Warning: Missing argument 2 for QueryBuilder::setParameter()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm tring to get events of a month and Symfony2 display this error :

> **Warning:** Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::setParameter(), called in *D:\Works\Development\www\intranet\src\Intranet\IntranetBundle\Entity\EventRepository.php* on line 22 and defined in *D:\Works\Development\www\intranet\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder.php* line 356

**indexAction**

```
$date_to   = $year . "-" . $m . "-01";
$date_from = $year . "-" . $m . "-" . $nDay;

$events = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getManager()
               ->getRepository('IntranetIntranetBundle:Event')
               ->getEventsOfTheMonth($date_to, $date_from);
```

**EventRepository**

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getEventsOfTheMonth($date_from, $date_to) {

        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
                  ->where('e.date BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to')
                  ->setParameter(array(
                      'date_from' => $date_from,
                      'date_to'   => $date_to
                    ))
                  ->orderBy('e.date', 'ASC');

        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L515

`setParameter($key, $value, $type)` does not expect an array while `setParameters($parameters)` does.

```
@param string|integer $key
```

Use the following:

```
// ...
->setParameter('date_from', $date_from)
->setParameter('date_to', $date_to)
```

... or ...

```
->setParameters( array(/* ... */))
```

... or ...

```
->setParameters(new ArrayCollection(array(
      new Parameter('date_from', $date_from),
      new Parameter('date_to', $date_to),
 )))
```

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L558

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `QueryBuilder::setParameters(array $parameters)` method, which expects an array.